# overlapping css of a table property with another

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am working on a web page which has a table with several columns as follows
[image]

In the above picture each td has blue border but I am trying increase thickness for left border of Ask1 using the following markup and CSS

**HTML**

```
 <td class="clientOffer1">Ask1</td>
```

**CSS**

```
clientOffer1 {
 border-left: 3px solid #0088cc;

}
```

but above CSS is replaced by the original css of td which is used for remaining columns which is as follows

```
td {
    padding: 1px;
    line-height: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    /*background-color:#3C78B5;*/
    vertical-align: auto;
    border: 1px solid #0088cc;
    width: 120px; 

}
```

**How do use both CSS without conflicting one another?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are selected with a leading period in CSS:

```
.clientOffer1 { ... }
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/zonoti/1/edit?html,css,output)</kbd>

```
td {
    padding: 1px;
    line-height: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    /*background-color:#3C78B5;*/
    vertical-align: auto;
    border: 1px solid #0088cc;
    width: 120px; 
}

.clientOffer1 {
    border-left: 3px solid #0088cc;
}
```

If you are still having troubles, it would be because some level of specificity is taking hold. Try the following:

```
.client {
  border-left: 3px solid #0088cc !important;
}
```

Here's some reading material:

- [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)